# Why is my vector not accumulating the iteration?

Tags: julia

I have this type of data that I want to send to a dataframe:

[image]

So, I am iterating through it and sending it to a vector. But my vector never keeps the data.

```
Dv = Vector{Dict}()
for item in reader
    push!(Dv,item)
end

length(Dv)
```

This is what I get:

[image: results]

And I am sure this is the right way to do it. It works in Python:

[image]

EDIT
This is the code that I use to access the data that I want to send to a dataframe:

```
results=pyimport("splunklib.results")

kwargs_oneshot = (earliest_time= "2019-09-07T12:00:00.000-07:00",
                  latest_time= "2019-09-09T12:00:00.000-07:00",
                  count=0)

searchquery_oneshot = "search index=iis | lookup geo_BST_ONT longitude as sLongitude, latitude as sLatitude | stats count by featureId | geom geo_BST_ONT allFeatures=True | head 2" 

oneshotsearch_results = service.jobs.oneshot(searchquery_oneshot; kwargs_oneshot...)

# Get the results and display them using the ResultsReader
reader = results.ResultsReader(oneshotsearch_results)

for item in reader
    println(item)
end
```

Comment: your code seems fine to me. can you post an example of `reader` as code, not a screenshot

Comment: `reader` might just be empty

Comment: the reader is not empty. The first image shows the results that I get.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ResultsReader` is a [streaming reader](https://docs.splunk.com/DocumentationStatic/JavaSDK/1.0/com/splunk/ResultsReader.html). This means you will "consume" its elements as you iterate over them. You can covert it to an array with `collect`. Do not print the items before you `collect`.

```
results=pyimport("splunklib.results")

kwargs_oneshot = (earliest_time= "2019-09-07T12:00:00.000-07:00",
                  latest_time= "2019-09-09T12:00:00.000-07:00",
                  count=0)

searchquery_oneshot = "search index=iis | lookup geo_BST_ONT longitude as sLongitude, latitude as sLatitude | stats count by featureId | geom geo_BST_ONT allFeatures=True | head 2" 

oneshotsearch_results = service.jobs.oneshot(searchquery_oneshot; kwargs_oneshot...)

# Get the results
reader = results.ResultsReader(oneshotsearch_results)

# collect them into an array
Dv = collect(reader)

# Now you can iterate over them without changing the result
for item in Dv
    println(item)
end
```

Comment: Why in Python it is not necessary to do that?

Comment: It is the same for Julia and Python. It seems that in your python code you are only iterating over `reader` once, but in your Julia example you are iterating over `reader` twice

Comment: I can even remove the FOR loop and send it directly to a DataFrame, in Julia.